# Scrollpane with jList in Japanel does not work

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

Edit

Here is your code in which projectList has a string too long which should make the scroll bar appear. but It does not. Rather it expands the frame size

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FooFrame extends JFrame {
private JList jList;
private String[] projectList = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nineeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"};
private DefaultListModel listItems;
private JScrollPane scrollpane;

public FooFrame() {
    JLabel lblHeading = new JLabel(
            " Demo text");
    JPanel mainLayout = new JPanel();
    mainLayout.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainLayout.add(lblHeading, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jList = new JList(projectList);

    // listItems = new DefaultListModel(); // wasted line since you don't use this
    jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(jList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    mainLayout.add(scrollpane); 
    add(mainLayout);
}

private static void createAndShowGui() {
    FooFrame frame = new FooFrame();
    frame.setSize(10,10);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   createAndShowGui();
}
```

}

A strange thing I noticed when trying to add JList in a Jscrollpane in a Japanel. If I try to add JList in a JscrollPane in a frame directly, it is done with ease. Where as if I am trying to add the same putting it in a panel(With border layout), it is not working for me.

here is the sample code

```
JLabel lblHeading = new JLabel(
            " Demo text");
    JPanel mainLayout = new JPanel();
    mainLayout.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainLayout.add(lblHeading, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jList = new JList(projectList);

    listItems = new DefaultListModel();
    jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(jList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    mainLayout.add(scrollpane); 
    add(mainLayout);
```

Irrespective of what I do, the text in the JList goes out of the frame and scrollbar doesnt appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will want to create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Comment: Yes, tried with it TT. It does not work for me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Gentleman, its 5-6 lines of code. I dont think it can go shorter. I need to add a JList in a JscrollPane which is inside a JPanel. I hope that specifies my problem clearly to you. Thanks for replying to my query

Comment: @TT.: that couldn't possibly change his outcome, since he's adding the JScrollPane in a default fashion, meaning it automatically places the JScrollPane in the BorderLayout.CENTER position. To Richard, again, there is nothing in your code that would explain your problem. Again, we really will want to see your [mcve].

Comment: ...................hello?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not a problem but rather a feature -- The JScrollPane is a smart component and won't show the scrollbar or scrollbar tabs unless they're needed, again, and this only occurs when the JScrollPane's viewport is smaller than the component it holds and displays. For example, if you artificially constrain the size of the containing JPanel, here done by overriding `getPreferredSize()`, the scrollbar tab is shown:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 200;
    private static final int PREF_H = 200;
    private static final String[] PROJECT_LIST = { "One", "Two", "Three",
            "FOURRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR" };
    private static final String TITLE_TEXT = "Demo Text";
    private JList<String> jList = new JList<>(PROJECT_LIST);

    public FooPanel() {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel(TITLE_TEXT, SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = Math.min(superSz.width, PREF_W);
        int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        FooPanel mainPanel = new FooPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```